# What should be done in a mergesort merge function when the array length is even numbered, especially with the case where size=2?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I've implemented a mergesort merge function, but although I copied it as best that I could, I've run into the issue when the left,middle,right parameters are 0,0,1. In this case, the logic seems to be totally ruined. When input array 14,7, it outputs 14,7. The reason is that left==middle and so it gets inserted immediately.

The mergesort function here passed test cases, but its only the merge function being debugged.

I would have thought that the 0,0,1 is an invalid parameter spec, but no, there is no other way to pass the middle element in an length=2 array.

I tried to base my code off of https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Sorting%20Algorithms/code/MergeSort.java

```
// Takes in an array that has two sorted subarrays,
//  from [p..q] and [q+1..r], and merges the array
var merge = function(array, p, q, r) {
  console.log(array);
  console.log(p);
  console.log(q);
  console.log(r);
  var tmp = {};
  var k = p;
  var middle = q;
  while(p<=middle && q <= r){
    console.log("aaa");
    console.log(array[p]);
    console.log(array[q]);
    console.log("bbb");

    if (array[p] < array[q]){
        tmp[k] = array[p];
        k++;
        p++;
    } else {
        tmp[k] = array[q];
        k++;
        q++;
    }
  }
  while(p<middle){
        //tmp[k] = array[p];
        k++;
    p++;
  }
  while(r >= q){
        //tmp[k] = array[q];
        k++;
    q++;
  }

  for(var i in tmp){
    array[i] = tmp[i];
  }
  console.log(array);
  console.log(tmp);
  console.log("test");
};


// Takes in an array and recursively merge sorts it
var mergeSort = function(array, p, r) {
    var lowerIndex = p;
    var higherIndex = r;
            if (lowerIndex < higherIndex) {
            var middle = Math.floor(lowerIndex + (higherIndex - lowerIndex) / 2);
            // Below step sorts the left side of the array
            mergeSort(array,lowerIndex, middle);
            // Below step sorts the right side of the array
            mergeSort(array,middle + 1, higherIndex);
            // Now merge both sides
            merge(array,lowerIndex, middle, higherIndex);
        }
};

var array = [14, 7, 3, 12, 9, 11, 6, 2];
array = [14, 7];
mergeSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
console.log("Array after sorting: " + array);
//Program.assertEqual(array, [2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14]);
```

Comment: Quicksort is one algorithm; merge sort is another. It doesn't matter whether the subarrays have different lengths. The error is most likely an inconsistent use of indices. Is `mid` the last element in the left array or the first element in the right array? The expression `while (p <= middle)` looks suspicious.

Comment: @MOehm Sorry about that. It is mergesort. The value "mid" in this case "q" is both the last element in the left and the first element in the right. That is because the array is [14,7] and there is no "middle" element. I'm not quite sure how to properly designate it in the odd case.

Comment: That was meant a rhetoric question to you. You should check whether `middle` is used consistently in your code.

Comment: @MOehm That is a good idea, but in this particular test case, there is no middle. The middle could be set to the upper bound, as in 0, 1, 1. The code above is wrong in that the middle is non-existent.

Comment: @MOehm It seems that the issue is that the code is designed to work with the middle being a part of the right array. I suppose that is a weird way of thinking about it, but the variable itself can belong to one side or the other.

I've gotten it to work by moving the middle, but can't yet figure out how it could work with the middle on the left (in what lay the difference)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mid index must belong to only one of the ranges. At the moment, you are using `<=` to compare so it belongs to both.

It seems to me it would be less confusing use the more common convention of expressing a range as the first index which is value and the first index which is invalid. Your input of `0,0,1` means that the first index ranges over *[0,0]* inclusive and your second index ranges over *[0,1]* inclusive. So at some point you compare the data at `array[0]` with itself, and then add it to the list of outputs. Making the mid and end points exclusive means the input for the ranges *[0,1)* and *[1,2)* are unambiguous. ( In a range, a round bracket denotes exclusive )

Comment: I see. Basically, the problem was the use of non-existent indexes, ie. iterating over 0,0 or over the whole series twice. I guess thats why the other code labeled "start" and "end" variable names. The <= btw is many cases.

Or, more simply, the use of the word "middle" was the error, because there was no middle, just leftEnd and/or rightStart. Not only a non-existent index, but a non-existent "middle". It didn't occur to me that I was the one who thought up that there was a "middle" and got tripped up by the lazy naming.

Answer (score 2):

In your nomenclature, the array bounds are inclusive: the lower bound is the first element of a range, the higher bound is the last element of the range. The `mid` element is the last element of the left subarray and therefore, the right array starts with `mid + 1`, as you can see in your calls:

```
        mergeSort(array, lowerIndex, middle);        // sort left array
        mergeSort(array, middle + 1, higherIndex);   // sot right array
```

But in `merge`, you assign `mid` to the right range: The index `q` should start at one element after the middle. (Plus, you use the limits inconsistently: In the first loop, where you pick the smalles element from either `p` or `q`, you test `p<=middle`, which is consistent with your nomenclature and later you use `p<middle`.

Here's your `merge` function corrected:

```
       var merge = function(array, p, middle, r) {
          console.log(p, q, r);
          var tmp = {};
          var k = p;
          var q = middle + 1;

          while(p <= middle && q <= r){
            if (array[p] < array[q]){
                tmp[k++] = array[p++];
            } else {
                tmp[k++] = array[q++];
            }
          }

          while(p <= middle) tmp[k++] = array[p++];
          while(q <= r) tmp[k++] = array[q++];

          for(var i in tmp) array[i] = tmp[i];
        }
```

I second Pete's suggestion to use *exclusive* upper bounds. In this nomenclature, The subarrays are `array[lo:mid]` and `array[mid:hi]`, because `mid` and `hi`, whose initial value is `array.length`, are not part of the range.